# Initialize a slider from external javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I use noUIslider and I try to initialize it from an external javascript file.

```
<div id="slider-med" class="slider-success"></div><input type="text" id="med-value" value="0"/>


$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#slider-med').noUiSlider({
  connect: 'lower',
  start: [ 4 ],
  step: 1,
  range: {
    'min': [  0 ],
    'max': [ 5 ]
  },
  format: wNumb({
    decimals: 0
  })
}); 
});
```

If I put the JS code in the end of the HTML file, it works. If I put it in an external JS file, it doesn't work. Since, I have a lot of sliders in the page, I want to keep it clear and have most of the JS code in external files.

**Edit**: this is the order of my scripts in the end of html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/noUiSlider/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/cookies.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js is the one with the sliders.

Comment: Does any error pop up?

Comment: Nothing. Neither on console on Firebug. Just the sliders don't initialized.

Comment: Could depend on order in which you put included files. It may miss jquery or slider if you put your external file before those.

Comment: Also if script is being included after current html you do not need $(document).ready, just launch $('#slider-med').noUiSlider

Comment: @mr.Pavlikov edited with the order

Comment: Can I see it somewhere on the web? Can you open `/static/js/custom.js` in your browser? Is it fine?

Comment: You can also add console.log('something') in that document.ready function to see if document ready fires. And try deleting document.ready wrapper at all.

Comment: Also, where does `wNumb` function come from?

Comment: @mr.Pavlikov it is from noUiSlider. I am trying to see the console log and if I don't find any error, I will upload it in another subdomain and post it here

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code inside`<head> </head>`

> don't use outside

```
<script src="your_JS_full_path.js"></script>
```

Comment: Scripts in `<head>` are usually a bad practice.

Comment: Doesn't work. Even if I prefer to not have js files in `<head>`